# Is it possible to list running programs/applications from web browser?

Tags: browser-extension

this is my first post so please forgive formatting and stuff :)

I need to be able to monitor what programs a user has running while on my site, I need this because of copyrighted  material that will be visible. So if a user has a banned program running I can detect it and stop the media.

I was thinking of using browser extensions but I don't know if accessing this information is possible ? 
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you looking for this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8101364/2706918 ?

Comment: Yes, I seen this before, im looking for something similar, ideally without the user needing to open all their security settings. Am I way off with the browser extension idea ?

Comment: I think you are trying to know whether any video/stream down-loader is running on user's system and then stop streaming of your media, before you go further, search 'online downloader' with google, you can't stop it!

Comment: If you did this to me, I would stop visiting your site. And if my browser did allow something like that, I would immediately stop using that browser. You have absolutely no right to spy on my system

Comment: I know I would be the same on normal sites, but in this context I think it is needed. What would you recommend instead then to prevent users from screen recording copyrighted material ? It would obviously only be used for legitimate reasons.

Comment: One possible solution is that, you may have your 'agent' program (not a browser extension) running on client machine which would help you to know what's going on client system! But as @a_horse_with_no_name said, he'll not visit your site! :)

Comment: sorry i missed your previous message NTN , yes i would be trying to see if the user had any screen cap software running, Ok cool i will look into that :) thanks for your time, and @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your feedback :D

Comment: Now, it's a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1790190/2706918