# How to detect. Through javascript if VirtualBox is open

Tags: javascript, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I would like to ask. Is it possible to make a web script that can detect if the user is running VirtualBox/Virt-Manager. Note that I am not asking to determine whether the OS is in a VM. I am talking about a situation when the OS is running on the host PC and the web master wants to take an action IF the user have one of those VM programs installed and open with VM's running.

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to get running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101364/javascript-to-get-running-processes)

Comment: Yes! `window.confirm("are you running a VM?")` possibility proven. But usable - most likely not.

Comment: That ALMOST gets it. While you can indeed detect the program running. It only shows the monitor itself (the window with the list of virtual machines the user have) it doesn't tell you if any of the VM's is running.

Comment: @JuanManuel You're not going to get that. Even just to get to the process list you have to have the user run a specific browser and reduce their security restrictions, and if you're counting on your users doing that for you then you may as well just ask them if they're running a VM.